# Swift global Array with table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create an empty global string arrray

```
struct GlobalVariables {
    static var globalString = [String]()
}
```

I would like to initialize it like this by putting string values into the array

```
func percentageCalculation() -> String {
        var FinalString = String()

        for i in 1...100 {
            let tstring = String("\(i)%\n")
            GlobalVariables.globalString[i] = tstring
        }

        return FinalString
    }
```

Then outputing global string values to my tableview.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        let testLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UITextView

       testLabel.text = GlobalVariables.globalString[indexPath.row]

        return cell!
    }
```

any advice on the best way to achieve this? This is my psuedo code of what im trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a struct to define a simple array. You can just define an array at a global level like this:

```
var globalString = [String]()
```

Once you have the array you can add your numbers to it like this:

```
for i in 1...100 {

    globalString.append("\(i)")
}
```

Then in your cellForRow you can just use this to populate the values:

```
testLabel.text = globalString[indexPath.row]
```